# Nodejs Webdav read multiple files (Problem with Array)

Tags: node.js, server, webdav, nextcloud

I am starting using NodeJs and webdav, I am using websockets to receive a list with the names of the images that I need to send to my app and then I have a for loop to send them to my app, but for some reason some of the images are undefined.

I am starting using NodeJs and webdav so I have no idea what's wrong.

```
        for(let i = 0; i < ImagemList.length; i++){
        wfs.readFile(ImagemList[i], "binary", function(err, data) {
            Imagens[i] = data;
            if(Imagens.length == ImagemList.length){
                socket.emit("ImagemPost", Imagens);
            }
        });
    }
```

For some reason I can't acess the variable "i" and for some reason the data was going to a random place leaving empty spots.

I've updated the code and it still goes to random places (don't know why) but doesn't leave any empty spot.

My array is still random if someone can help me.

```
    Imagem = Imagem.replace("[", "");
    Imagem = Imagem.replace("]", "");
    let ImagemList = Imagem.split(", ");
    let Imagens = [];
    let contador = 0;
    for(let o = 0; o < ImagemList.length; o++){
        wfs.readFile(ImagemList[o], "binary", function(err, data) {
            Imagens[contador] = (data);
            contador++;
            if(Imagens.length == ImagemList.length){
                socket.emit("ImagemPost", Imagens);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you send `Buffer` over a websocket? Just guessing

Comment: Yes it's possible. The problem was that I couldn't acess the variable "i" so for some reason the buffer was going to a random place on my array, it still is but at least I can receive the list.